# How to set the correct path of android-sdk in fresh android studio installation?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

I installed Android Studio using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-make
umake android --accept-license
```

When I launched Android Studio:

[image: screenshot of Android Studio Setup Wizard]

Should I select another location?

Answer (score 1):

[**From Official Documentation:**](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio0814inbetachannel)

> Please find a different place to put the SDK (for example
> **~/android-sdk**), and then point your SDK to this directory location
> instead. You can do this either by opening up the Project Structure
> Dialog and selecting the SDK Location tab, or if you try to load a
> project which is using the old location, you'll be prompted for the
> new location:

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, most probably you will find sdk in `/home/{username}/Android/Sdk` if you have downloaded the android-sdk through Android Studio.
In case you haven't downloaded yet then

- Open Android Studio
- Go to Configure
- SDK Manager
- Select SDK Platform version and tools
- Apply